# Default file extension for `dired-do-rename`

Tags: dired

I am wondering how to make renaming files in dired to use the current file extension as the default.

For example, imagine I run `dired-do-rename` on the file `foo.bar` and then type `foo2` and press Enter. I would like the result of this operation to yield the file `foo2.bar` in my directory.

Comment: There are so many possibilities for what someone might prefer as the default behavior in such a case. Keep in mind too that the single-file rename is not the general or typical use case for `dired-do-rename`. There is option `dired-dwim-target`, but its "do-what-I-mean" behavior is not what you mean (;-)).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `dired-do-rename` for your use case. Just do this:

1. `C-x C-q` to make the directory listing editable (writable).
2. Insert `2` in the name where you want it (or otherwise edit the name).
3. `C-x C-q` to make the listing read-only again.

You can use any editing commands and keys you like: `M-%` (`query-replace`) etc.

Comment: Thanks. But I can still get this behavior by using `M-n` following `dired-do-rename`. What I would like is the default suggestion following either `dired-do-rename` or Wdired to contain _only_ the extension with the cursor placed before the period. I occasionally rename long filenames and would still benefit from a default of the current extension although I wouldn't want to default to the whole filename and manually delete everything besides the extension.